# Generate xls-file from HSSFWorkbook

Tags: excel, file, export, apache-poi, arrays

I am creating an excel-file:

```
public byte[] createReport() {
    List<ExportModel> exportModels = export.computeExportModels();
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = excelCreator.createWorkbook(exportModels);

    // return workbook.getBytes();
    return getByteArray(workbook);
}

private byte[] getByteArray(HSSFWorkbook workbook) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        workbook.write(bos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

While this does work, it doesn't work with

```
workbook.getBytes();
```

If i try to open the generated xls-file, Excel just crashes and can't open it. Do you have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Apache POI javadocs for HSSFWorkbook.getBytes()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#getBytes%28%29):

> public byte[] getBytes()
>
> Method getBytes - get the bytes of just the HSSF portions of the XLS file. Use this to construct a POI POIFSFileSystem yourself.

Excel `.xls` files *must* be wrapped in an outer OLE2 container, eg as generated by POIFSFileSystem. As such, you either need to do all that yourself, or just call [HSSFWorkbook.write(OutputStream)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#write%28java.io.OutputStream%29) which does it all for you (as the [javadocs explain](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#write%28java.io.OutputStream%29))

If you want to write a HSSFWorkbook out, and get the bytes for it, then unless you want to do something very special just do:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
workbook.write(baos);
bytes[] excelFile = baos.toByteArray();
```